# Select from parent-children xml content

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been looking for solution for selecting parent-child relation from table [Group] which contains a xml column.

[Group] table has the following structure:

- ID - int
- Content - xml

There is xml data - parent-child relation in column Content

```xml
<root>
    <person name="John">
        <device name="notebook" />
        <device name="xbox" />   
    </person>
    <person name="Jane">
        <device name="TV" />
    </person>
    <person name="Mark">
    </person>
</root>
```

I would like to select data in the following format:

| Group Id | PersonName | DeviceName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | notebook |
| 1 | John | xbox |
| 1 | Jane | TV |

Because Mark has no device assigned, there is no row for Mark in result.
Is it possible to achieve this result in a `SELECT` query?

Comment: Have you had a look at the XQuery tools SQL Server has? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I think that problem is only my skill with this technology. I am able to select only select parent nodes, but I don't know how to join it with child nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, you can use XQuery for this. As you don't want any rows for Mark, I go straight to the `device` node, in the `nodes` method, as this means that no rows for Mark will be found. Then you can go back up one level to get the person's name:

```sql
SELECT V.ID AS GroupID,
       p.d.value('../@name','nvarchar(50)') AS PersonName,
       p.d.value('@name','nvarchar(50)') AS DeviceName
FROM(VALUES(1,CONVERT(xml,'<root>
    <person name="John">
        <device name="notebook" />
        <device name="xbox" />   
    </person>
    <person name="Jane">
        <device name="TV" />
    </person>
    <person name="Mark">
    </person>
</root>')))V(ID, Content)
     CROSS APPLY V.Content.nodes('root/person/device') p(d);
```

Comment: Thank you, It works like a charm.  Can I have one more question? What selector can I use If person is ancestor instead of parent (If device should be nested in subelement at any level)

Comment: ***If*** I am understanding correctly, you would go to the `device` node (using the `nodes` method), and then use an additional call to the `nodes` method for the `person` node (in another `APPLY`).